# install kohana website on multiple servers

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, virtualhost

I have a Kohana 3.0.14 website that i want to put on multiple domains, having associated a virtual host each (different ips).

the difference between my websites is the configuration file and the boostrap file (where i set the language to be used).

All the sites are in production.

How can i 'breakup' the website, how can i include the files so that i would have all the kohana site in a single place, and the config and boostrap on every server, so that when i am fixing an error to be fixed on every site (every domain)?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by setting up an environment variable at the top of you index.php file. Then depending on this variable, you'll set the configuration variables, languages, etc. This is usually how I handle staging/live/local environments, and doing so allows you to keep all the code identical between the various installations.

For example, in **index.php**:

```
define("ENV", "staging")
```

Then in **bootstrap.php**:

```
$baseUrl = "http://defaultdomain.com/";
if (ENV == "staging") $baseUrl = "http://staging.somedomain.com/";

Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => $baseUrl,
));
```

In **database.php**:

```
if (ENV == "live") {
    $hostname = ...
    $database = ...
    $username = ...
    $password = ...
} else if (ENV == "staging") {
    $hostname = ...
    $database = ...
    $username = ...
    $password = ...
}

return array
(
    'default' => array
    (
        'type'       => 'mysql',
        'connection' => array(
            'hostname'   => $hostname,
            'database'   => $database,
            'username'   => $username,
            'password'   => $password,
            'persistent' => FALSE,
        ),
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'caching'      => FALSE,
        'profiling'    => TRUE,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting options are limited, your best bet is to choose the first primary domain and create an account using that. Then park more domains on top. Then simply get the URL to decide what language etc you want to use.